# adding date time stamp to a query output in access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a simple query in access which displays data from a single table. The query is being executed on a button click. I want to display the Date and Time stamp in the query output everytime the button is clicked.

How can I display Date and Time in the query output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a column, but it will display the date for each row:

```
Timestamped: Now()
```

In SQL view that would be:

```
SELECT Now() As Timestamped FROM MyTable
```

EDIT

Date only with row number:

```
SELECT 
   a.ID, 
   Date() & Format((
      SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM Table1 b 
      WHERE b.ID <= a.ID),"-00") AS Timestamped
FROM Table1 AS a
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Note that whatever you choose as ID must be unique and that this could make a query slow.

Comment: Is there a way to format the The Stamp? to MMDDYY and display an incrementor after it. for e.g. for first record it would display 022412-01 for second record 022412-02 and so on

Comment: That depends - do you have an `ORDER BY` clause in your statement?  If no, then it doesn't matter (ordering is 'random' if not specified).  If yes... you need the OLAP function `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @X-Zero any such function for access?

Comment: @X-Zero ROW_NUMBER() is not available in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou - Ah, thanks, I didn't know.  But without it, you've demonstrated pretty much the only option left, which will eat into the performance of the query.  Does Access support CTEs?  If the result set is small (and there are restrictions on the initial selection), it may benefit you to create a temp table.

Comment: @X-Zero, no it does not. This is really a misuse of MS Access in that the best way to display the output with row numbers would be a report. Access is not a database, it is a development tool that commonly uses a Jet/ACE database. However, sometimes people post questions without saying why they wish to do things in an odd way, and it is possible that there is a valid reason.